# How to use System.getProperty("user.home") in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

As we know we can use System.getProperty("user.home") method in java and it returns some specific path.
Can we do this in Ext JS to get the same path as like java does, if not then what is the way to achieve this, is there is some function as like java in Ext JS?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no this is not possible, cause ExtJS runs in the browser. the browser must not access for security reasons any system environment variables.

ExtJs can only give you the operating system or browser type:

```
Ext.isWindows etc.
Ext.isIE etc.
```